# IntelliJ IDEA run configuration related to current class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my IntelliJ IDEA, I have many classes in my project. And there are more than a dozen configurations each related to a different class.

Is there a way to run the configuration related to current select(or displayed or active) class without find the corresponding configuration from the long list using my eye?

Comment: isnt it alt shift f10 or ctrl alt shift f10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run each class by clicking on the green arrow:

[image]

The Screenshot is taken from IntelliJ Version 2016.3 UE